# Could some one explain how the algorithm binary exponentiation from right to left works

Tags: algorithm, multiplication

I am looking into the Binary exponentiation and how they work from left to right and right to left. I am able to figure out the "Left to Right" method. But not able to figure out the "Right to Left" method.

Here is the link I have followed. [Link](https://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=BinaryExponentiation)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that in each iteration of the loop, `y` is the place value of the next digit; if that digit is 1, then what is left of `n` will be odd, so it gets included in the result `r`.  Setting `n = floor(n/2)` in each iteration effectively removes the least-significant digit from `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Left to right: square previous and possibly multiply by `x`

```
x^1 = x
x^11 = x²x
x^110 = (x²x)²
x^1100 = ((x²x)²)²
x^11001 = ((x²x)²)²x
```

Right to left: possibly multiply previous by a power of `x`

```
x^1 = x, p = x
x^01 = x, p = x²
x^001 = x, p = (x²)²
x^1001 = (x²)²x, p = ((x²)²)²
x^11001 = ((x²)²)²(x²)²x
```

Comment: @BaradwajAryasomayajula: I am glad that it suits you.